# Centos 6.9 version 2.6.32-696.el6.X86_64

Tags: centos

where I can find version 2.6.32-696.el6.X86_64 CentOS 6.9 iso image

Thanks

Comment: "2.6.32-696.el6.X86_64" : If it's not the version included in the '28 Mar 2017' ISO http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/centos.org/6.9/isos/x86_64/ ... then you can build the packages from the source ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/kernel-2.6.32-696.el6.src.rpm

Answer (score 1):

Specific kernel revisions for a distribution are generally not released in ISO image format.